# sql inconsistent datatypes: expected number got char

Tags: sql, varchar, case-when

I am trying to write a `Case When` statement, but I get an inconsistent datatypes error. I need 'Returned' displayed if the first when statement is not met.

```
CASE
WHEN (X.RECEIVED_QTY = 0) THEN FLOOR(SYSDATE-INVENTORY_TRANS.TRANSACTION_DATE) 
WHEN (X.RECEIVED_QTY = 0) THEN 'RETURNED'
END AS DAYS_OUT
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't mix results of a `CASE` statement, that means you can't return an `INT` under one condition and a `VARCHAR` in another.  If you want to return `Returned` then you will need to `CONVERT` or `CAST` your numeric values to `VARCHAR`

You also have a syntactical problem with your CASE.

You'd have to change it to something like this:

```
CASE X.RECEIVED_QTY 
  WHEN 0 THEN CAST( FLOOR(SYSDATE-INVENTORY_TRANS.TRANSACTION_DATE) AS VARCHAR(20))
  ELSE 'RETURNED'
END AS DAYS_OUT
```